# sql union all instruction issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

First I run this query that creates a table and insert two rows of data.

```
declare @data table (date varchar(10),x1 int,x2 int,x3 int,y1 int,y2 int,y3 int,z1  numeric(5,2),z2  numeric(5,2),z3 numeric(5,2))

insert into @data values ('2017-05-15',11,12,15,21,31,41,0.1,0.4,0.5)

insert into @data values ('2017-05-16',11,12,15,21,31,41,0.1,0.4,0.5)
```

Then I run this query to convert my rows in tables:

```
select date,x1 as 'a1',y1 as 'b1', z1 as 'c1' from @data    
union all     
select date,x2 as 'a2',y2 as 'b2', z2 as 'c2' from @data    
union all    
select date,x3 as 'a3',y3 as 'b3', z3 as 'c3' from @data    
order by date
```

I get this result

```
2017-05-15  11  21  0.10
2017-05-15  12  31  0.40
2017-05-15  15  41  0.50
2017-05-16  15  41  0.50
2017-05-16  12  31  0.40
2017-05-16  11  21  0.10
```

First table (first 3 rows) is generating OK, 2nd is reversed. Then 3rd is again ok and so on...

Please try to run this query to understand what I mean.

Kbv.

Comment: Post your desired output and the meaning or logic behind it please. Also tag which database are you working with (Oracle, SQL Server, MySql, etc.).

Comment: What is this supposed to mean:  "First table is generating OK, 2nd is reversed. Then 3rd is again ok and so on..." ?  Your question only references one table.

Comment: What's the current result, and what's the expected result? (Formatted text, not images, please.)

Comment: Don't store dates in varchar columns. Use a proper date data type!

Comment: The column names `a2`, `a3` etc are ignored

Comment: You are only ordering by `date`, so why expect an extra ordering?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to show a 3x3 matrix that is stored as a row. If that is the case then you can add a hard-coded number in each matrix row and order by that number after the date:

```
select 1 as ordernumber, date,x1 as 'a1',y1 as 'b1', z1 as 'c1' from @data

union all

select 2 as ordernumber, date,x2 as 'a2',y2 as 'b2', z2 as 'c2' from @data

union all

select 3 as ordernumber, date,x3 as 'a3',y3 as 'b3', z3 as 'c3' from @data

order by date, ordernumber
```

If you don't want to display that number, then use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    date,
    a1,
    b1,
    c1
FROM
(
    select 1 as ordernumber, date,x1 as 'a1',y1 as 'b1', z1 as 'c1' from @data

    union all

    select 2 as ordernumber, date,x2 as 'a2',y2 as 'b2', z2 as 'c2' from @data

    union all

    select 3 as ordernumber, date,x3 as 'a3',y3 as 'b3', z3 as 'c3' from @data
) AS T
order by 
    date, 
    ordernumber
```

Comment: @KushantVyas Edited.